# I could not see button on the browser

Tags: javascript

The following scipt returns the width and height of the document (the HTML document) and window . But its return error.

```
    <html>
     <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
         </script>
          <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
             $("button").click(function(){
               var txt="";
              txt+="Document width/height: " + $(document).width();
             txt+="x" + $(document).height() + "\n";
              txt+="Window width/height: " + $(window).width();
           txt+="x" + $(window).height();
           alert(txt);
           });
          });

         </head>
              <body>

               <button>Display dimensions of document and window</button>

                  </body>
                      </html>
```

Comment: What's the error? And you should use the latest version of jQ.

Comment: there are no error, just close the script before the head tag

Comment: You're missing the `</script>` tag and your question looks to us pretty much like this: http://jsbin.com/pehas/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

the closing `<script>` tag is missing just before the head tag

Answer (score 1):

right.. `</script>` is missing replace the below

```
</head>
<body>
```

by

```
</script>
</head>
<body>
```